# Groupby and calculating count for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of dataframe

```
H = Home win
D = Draw
A = Away win

            Datetime    HomeTeam            AwayTeam            HG  AG  FT
0   2021-02-17 22:00:00 Colo Colo           U. De Concepcion    1   0   H
1   2021-02-15 14:30:00 Cobresal            U. Espanola         4   1   H
2   2021-02-14 22:00:00 Deportes Iquique    S. Wanderers        2   0   H
3   2021-02-14 22:00:00 La Serena           A. Italiano         0   2   A
4   2021-02-14 22:00:00 O'Higgins           Colo Colo           1   1   D
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I want to count the previous wins of teams per match in the rows. I can do it with this code:

```
_hometeam_count = df.groupby("HomeTeam").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:, :]["FT"].count())
_hometeam_sum = df[df['FT'] == 'H'].groupby("HomeTeam").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:, :]["FT"].count())

df1["WinsH/MPH"] = df["HomeTeam"].apply(lambda x: (_hometeam_sum.loc[x] if x in _hometeam_sum.index else 0) / (_hometeam_count.loc[x] if x in _hometeam_count.index else 0))
```

But there is an issue it start to count always from the first row, if a match in the row 19 should count from that row instead from the row 1. How can I fix the code, to do the calculations for each row?

```
               Datetime          HomeTeam          AwayTeam  HG  AG FT  HG_1ST  AG_1ST FT_1ST  HG_2ND  AG_2ND FT_2ND     1     X     2  WinsH/MPH
0    2021-02-17 22:00:00         Colo Colo  U. De Concepcion   1   0  H       1       0      H       0       0      D  2.53  3.01  2.80   0.352941
2    2021-02-14 22:00:00  Deportes Iquique      S. Wanderers   2   0  H       0       0      D       2       0      H  3.13  3.55  2.08   0.312500
3    2021-02-14 22:00:00         La Serena       A. Italiano   0   2  A       0       0      D       0       2      A  2.14  3.22  3.31   0.312500
4    2021-02-14 22:00:00         O'Higgins         Colo Colo   1   1  D       0       0      D       1       1      D  2.27  3.14  3.10   0.187500
..                   ...               ...               ...  ..  .. ..     ...     ...    ...     ...     ...    ...   ...   ...   ...        ...
302  2020-01-26 16:00:00      S. Wanderers       U. Catolica   0   3  A       0       1      A       0       2      A  3.75  3.23  1.97   0.500000
303  2020-01-26 00:30:00       A. Italiano          Cobresal   4   1  H       1       1      D       3       0      H  2.12  3.31  3.23   0.375000
304  2020-01-25 16:00:00       Antofagasta          Coquimbo   2   1  H       2       0      H       0       1      A  2.19  3.20  3.16   0.437500
305  2020-01-25 01:00:00         O'Higgins   Union La Calera   1   2  A       0       1      A       1       1      D  2.24  3.17  3.10   0.187500
306  2020-01-24 22:30:00           Everton  U. De Concepcion   2   1  H       0       1      A       2       0      H  1.76  3.45  4.52   0.375000
```

In last rows the expected result in "WinsH/MPH" should be 0 because there is no previous matches

Comment: Will be helpful if you can give an expected output to clearly highlight the difference

Comment: You are right, post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can use for these kind of analyses is the .cumsum() method. If you have floats or ints in a column, you can easily add up the wins up to that point. Make sure to have the order correct (do some simple tests). For example:

```
df['wins_so_far'] = df['win'].cumsum()
df['win_pct_so_far'] = df['win'].cumsum() / (df['win'].cumsum() + df['loss'].cumsum())
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, cumsum() could be good for this case but I don't have ints or floats but strings

Comment: Right. I think that will make your life easier though. You can create a new column like df['home_win'] = df['AG'] < df['HG']or something like that. It creates a Bool which you can also use for cumsum.

Comment: Ok, and how to groupby by teams columns?

Comment: If you have the home win column as a boolean, you can do df.groupby['HomeTeam'].cumsum() to get the cumulative home wins up to that point for each row.

Comment: Ok, and to start sum one row up? I don't want consider the current row in the calculation

Comment: I have not tested it but that is something like this: df.groupby['HomeTeam'].shift(1).cumsum() or df.groupby['HomeTeam'].cumsum().shift(1)

Comment: And for groupby both HomeTeam and AwayTeam, how could be possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233134/discussion-between-rutger-and-jognilie).